# Slow import and automatic generation of code from XML

Tags: haskell

I've been playing with Haskell and writing some code to parse DICOM medical images. The code is [here](https://plooney@bitbucket.org/plooney/lamdicom.git). I wanted to create a function that will take in a ByteString and return a name. So a certain ByteString (actually two Int64s taken from a ByteString) would return PatientName or StudyDate for example. There are thousands of these and they are all contained within an XML file. So to create the function I parse the XML file and generate the desired function and output to a file using

```
writeTagNameFromElemGroup :: FilePath -> [(String,String,String,String)] -> IO()
writeTagNameFromElemGroup fp tups = init >> Prelude.appendFile fp ( Prelude.drop 0 tags )
    where init = Prelude.appendFile fp "\ntagNameFromElem :: Element -> Group -> String\ntagNameFromElem e g\n"
      tags = LS.concat $ Prelude.map (\tup -> "    | " ++ (writeTup tup) ++ "\n") filTups
      hexInt x = show . readHex $ x
      filTups = LS.filter (\(w,x,y,z) -> Prelude.length w == 4 && Prelude.length x ==4 ) tups
```

This creates the desired function in Tags.hs

```
tagNameFromElem :: Int64 -> Int64 -> String
tagNameFromElem e g
    | e == 8 && g == 1 = "LengthToEnd"
    | e == 8 && g == 5 = "SpecificCharacterSet"
    | e == 8 && g == 6 = "LanguageCodeSequence"
    | e == 8 && g == 8 = "ImageType"
    | e == 8 && g == 16 = "RecognitionCode"
    | e == 8 && g == 18 = "InstanceCreationDate"
    | e == 8 && g == 19 = "InstanceCreationTime"
    | e == 8 && g == 20 = "InstanceCreatorUID"
    | e == 8 && g == 22 = "SOPClassUID"
    | e == 8 && g == 24 = "SOPInstanceUID"
    | e == 8 && g == 26 = "RelatedGeneralSOPClassUID"
    | e == 8 && g == 27 = "OriginalSpecializedSOPClassUID"
    ..... > 2000 more
```

Every so often there is a special case like

```
    | e == 1000 && mod (g -5) 10 == 0 = "ShiftTableTriplet"
```

which put me off just using a map.

Now this approach works but it takes a very long time to load (Over a minute) the whole which makes me think that I'm not doing this how it should be done. To reproduce I suggest cloning the repo and loading the Tags.hs.

A SSCE

```
writeFunc :: (Num x, Show x) => FilePath -> [x] -> IO()
writeFunc fp xs  = init >> Prelude.appendFile fp ( maps ) >> Prelude.appendFile fp "|  otherwise = 0 "
    where init = Prelude.appendFile fp "mapVal :: Int -> Int \nmapVal x\n    "
          maps = concat $ Prelude.map (\x -> "| x == " ++ show x ++ " = " ++ show (x +1 ) ++ "\n    ") xs
```

Use a long list ~ few thousand values and try to import the resulting file

Comment: Your first condition is matching on the value of `e`, could you possibly use a `Map Int64 (Int64 -> String)` where your `e` is the key and `(Int64 -> String)` is a function that returns the appropriate string based on the value of `g`?  You could then split this huge function into several smaller ones (they'd still be relatively large, but smaller than 2000 lines), but it'd probably compile a bit faster.  Alternatively, consider doing nested case statements, i.e. `case e of { 8 -> case g of { 1 -> "LengthToEnd"; ... }; ...}`.

Comment: It wouldn't be as pretty, but generated code doesn't have to be.

Comment: Following bheklilr's idea, you could catch the special cases (supposing they're just a few of them) using pattern matching, and the "_" pattern would default to a Map lookup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on what bheklilr suggested in the question's comments. Code generation is up to you.

I reviewed your code and found that there are only two values in which `e` imposes special conditions on `g`: `e == 28` and `e == 1000`. So, it'd be better to handle those in separate functions. Choose better names than the following ones, please.

```
e28 :: Map Int64 String
e28 = fromList [ (0, "CodeLabel"), (2, "NumberOfTables"), ... ]

e1000 :: Map Int64 String
e1000 :: fromList [ (0, "EscapeTriplet"), (1, "RunLengthTriplet"), ... ]
```

The keys of the previous maps are taken from your special-case predicate: `mod (g - key) 10 == 0`.

The case where `e == 1010` is also special, since it doesn't depend on `g`. It's always "ZonalMap", so it'll be dealt with later.

Now, just create the rest of maps using `g` as key.

```
e40 :: Map Int64 String
e40 = fromList [ (2, "SamplesPerPixel"), (3, "SamplesPerPixelUsed"), ... ]

e84 :: Map Int64 String
e84 = fromList [ ... ]

...
```

Create a map from regular `e`s (i.e. not the 28, 1000 or 1010 ones) to their corresponding map:

```
regularE :: Map Int64 (Map Int64 String)
regularE e = fromList [ (40, e40), (84, e84), ... ]
```

To sum it all up:

```
import Control.Monad

tagNameFromElem :: Int64 -> Int64 -> Maybe String
tagNameFromElem   28 g = lookup e28 (mod g 10)
tagNameFromElem 1000 g = lookup e1000 (mod g 10)
tagNameFromElem 1010 _ = Just "ZonalMap"
tagNameFromElem    e g = lookup regularE e >>= (`lookup` g)
```

The `lookup` function is from Data.Map, just in case qualification is required. Using `Maybe` handles the case where `e` or `g` do not map to a valid tag name, instead of a hardcoded "Not Found" string.

Note that I haven't tested this code; I'm not at home right now.

If you want, try `IntMap` instead of `Map`. You'll need to work with regular `Int`s in this case, but it may be good for this project.

Comment: This is the exact kind of solution I was suggesting, doing a very large case statement like that would give long compile times and poor performance since it's treated as a linear lookup table, whereas a `Map` gives better big-O complexity and can compress the code to only a few lines.

Comment: @bheklilr I came up with the solution after reading the question, then I read your comment and thought "some one got there first". So, I just elaborated a bit more in order to handle special and regular cases using Maps. The core idea is the one you described.

Comment: I still like IntMaps better, but they don't work with Int64. Using `fromIntegral` solves that, though.

Comment: I agree, `IntMap` would be more efficient would be easy to use in this situation.  If there is a specific need for `Int64`, `Data.Map` should suffice, although it will be somewhat slower (probably not noticeably though)